# Is it possible to build editText boxes like a listView?

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-edittext

So basically what I would love to do is to be able to build up a list of editable fields using editText boxes. However, instead of going into my XML layout and adding a new editText each time I want to add something to the list, is there a way to do this similarly to building a listView? That is, every time I add to my array of editViews the new editView is "automatically" added?

So basically, I'm referring to this example for a listView:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

In this example, if you simply add to the items in the following XML, you get more list items to appear in your app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="countries_array">
        <item>Bahrain</item>
        <item>Bangladesh</item>
        <item>Barbados</item>
        <item>Belarus</item>
        <item>Belgium</item>
        <item>Belize</item>
        <item>Benin</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Is there a way to do this for editText Views? Or even some other kind of editable widget?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the TextView in the list_item.xml from that tutorial to be an EditText instead and see what happens...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</EditText>
```

Comment: It works kind of goofy, but I'll have to mess with it a bit more. Maybe I can get it to work.

Comment: @CrazyJay: lol, I didn't say it would be perfect, I was just trying to point you in the right direction. :) It works because EditText is a subclass of TextView and the basic ListView adapter only needs something it can call 'setText()' for. You can put pretty much anything in a ListView but the more complex it gets, the more you have to use more complex Adapters and sometimes override the way they write the data. Good luck, hope you get it to work.